# How to hide an element in jsp file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

```
<li><label>Email:</label> <input type='text' name='username'
                            id="forgot_username" /></li>
                        <li><label>&nbsp;</label> <input type="submit"
                            id="forgot_btn" value="Send Reminder" class="btn"></li>
```

I have above text box and button in my jsp. and the below condition, what i want is when this condition occur , above text box and button should hide how can i do it.

```
<c:if test="${param.message == 3}">
                        <span class="error"><font color="red"> Email does not match</font></span>
                    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you put those `<li>` elements inside an identical  construct?

If you can't put those elements together and don't want to repeat the condition, you can always define a new variable:

```
<c:set var="condition" value="0">
<c:if test="${param.message == 3}">
    <c:set var="condition" value="1">
</c:if>

<c:if test="${condition == 1}">
                        <span class="error"><font color="red"> Email does not match</font></span>
                    </c:if>

....

<c:if test="${condition == 1}">
<li><label>Email:</label> <input type='text' name='username'
                            id="forgot_username" /></li>
                        <li><label>&nbsp;</label> <input type="submit"
                            id="forgot_btn" value="Send Reminder" class="btn"></li>
</c:if>
```

This way those `<li>` will be hidden even if the client has JS disabled, or any kind of JS problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should put div tags around the first code like this:

```
<div id="hide"> 
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id="forgot_username" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" id="forgot_btn" value="Send Reminder" class="btn">
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And then you can hide like this:

```
<c:if test="${param.message == 3}">

    <script>
        $('#hide').hide();
    </script>

    <span class="error"><font color="red"> Email does not match</font></span>
</c:if>
```